# What is wrong with this javascript script with a php declaration

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, variables

I would like to set a javascript variable 'logged_in' to either 1 or 0, depending on whether a user is logged in Wordpress. This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var logged_in = <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '1';} else {echo '0';} ?>;
</script>
```

But it's not working. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Define "now working". A more complete example would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe is_user_logged_in() is not defined if that's all you have?

Comment: What does the rendered code look like?

Comment: The variable doesn't get set to 1 or 0

Comment: is_user_logged_in() is a wordpress function. I'm running this script on a wordpress site

Comment: Shorthand; <?php echo is_user_logged_in() ? 1 : 0 ;  ?>.

Comment: View the generated page source. What do you see?

Comment: is_user_logged_in() is not found !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked your coding. Your code will define the variable you declared in your script as 1 if true and 0 if false. Keep in mind that you are only defining a variable and it will not do anything as it is. Here is what I have. Just take a look your source code.

```
<?php
function is_user_logged_in() {
return true;
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var logged_in = <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '1';} else {echo '0';} ?>;
</script>
```

If it is not setting the variable make sure that the `function is_user_logged_in()` exist and is available on the script.